# Why Drive Quick start sample always showing Authenticate

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am new to Android, Now i need to integrate my app with Google Drive i have search google a lot, i have got Drive quick start sample from git hub (https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) but while i am running it is always showing Mail authentication Dialog. please help me.

And also i have tried Quick start guide but i have failed in that also always showing 400 error or 403 error

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes i solved this

Comment: ok, it would be great if you can post how you solve the issue

Comment: I am not sure about Sample Quick drive. But i solved in my app. we need to Authorize with our Email information(It is used to find out in which Googele Drive account we need to store our data). And one more thing i didn't follow Android method, i used Java codes and informations

Answer (score 0):

Every request from your application sends to the Drive API must include an  [authorization token](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro). The token also identifies your application to Google, your application must use  [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular scope of access. Google displays a 'consent screen' to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data. If the use approves, the Google gives your application a access token. If Google determine that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.

**400 Bad request**. This can mean that a required field or parameter has not been provided, the value supplied is invalid or combination of provided fields is invalid. For more information, you may check the Official Google Documentation on how to handle API Errors and suggested actions: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors